# Model Builder iteration process problem: could not create the output tables invalid extension

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, zonal-statistics, iterator

I encountered problems with my Model Builder in Arcmap 10.4: [image]

I want to perform some statistics on my rasters using the same polygon (buffer). I use the Raster Iteretor and I did check if the extent of my input were the same. Actually it worked when using "zonal Statistics", but I needed to collect the values in a table (using "zonal statistics as table"). When I used zonal Statistics as table, the model doesn't work because of the tif extension present in the name of my raster inputs. How can I deal with that problem? . Any suggestion ?

Comment: What kind of iterator is it? What do you mean by "cant access output"? What is the complete path of the last output?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/153741. Please, merge your accounts. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. Tks and welcome.

Comment: You need to amend your question to show us how you set up the zonal statistics tool as it is not possible to help you until we see what you have actually done. As a side note it is OK to rename the inputs/outputs of tool but never change the name of the tool as that tells us what is actually running. It appears you have renamed the iterator to simple "Iterate" but as @BERA asks which iterator? I see you have added this information to your question, would have been much clearer if you had left it as its default name which describes what it is.

Comment: I presume you validate your model before running the iteration, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/validating-a-model.htm.

Comment: Anyone please respond?